# vmware disk activity (read) never stop, after start read file inside Virtual Machine(ubuntu)

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

When I use vm a long time, or started operations with big files in my vm, periodially I get bug: process `vmware-vmx.exe` never stop disk activity and vm stops responding(or very slow).

Host system: windows 10;
Client (usual): ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

That problem happened on different disks (samsung, seagate) and different client systems (various ubuntu).

All disks have alot of free place and don't have bad sectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem resolved: just update vmware with 12.1.0 to 12.5.2 and in a vm-ubuntu system: etc/fstab swap should not be disabled.